# How do I extract all .htaccess files from a tarball?

Tags: filenames, tar, wildcards

I want to extract all .htaccess files from a tarball, how can I do so? I see only one mention of "include" in the manual page of `tar` which is not related with an option for including only certain filenames at all.

Is there an alternative other than mentioning all paths as argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**GNU** tar supports "--wildcards" option.

```
tar tvfz file.tar.gz --wildcards '*/.htaccess'
```

Comment: Wow, I haven't even considered using wildcards for tar. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not a single command, but this works:

```
$ tar -ztvf tarball.tar.gz | grep .htaccess | awk '{print $9}'>files
$ cat files
1/.htaccess
2/.htaccess
$ tar -zxvT files -f tarball.tar.gz 
x 1/.htaccess
x 2/.htaccess
```

Comment: your solution is far more portable than mine.

Comment: This can be simplified to `tar tzf tarball.tar.gz | grep .htaccess > files`. Before andcoz' answer, I've succesfully used `tar xf tarball.tar.gz -T <(tar tf tarball.gz | grep -F .htaccess)`. I still like andcoz' answer more because it's shorter to type

Comment: Also, don't forget to `rm files` when done, or you may be quite confused in a month or two..  ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
tar tf tarball.tar.gz | grep '/\.htaccess$' | tar xfT tarball.tar.gz -
```

Comment: Smart use of the word for standard input (`-`)

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on andcoz's accepted answer to point out the differences between `gnutar` and `bsdtar` ...

```
# tar (GNU tar) 1.26
# bsdtar 2.8.4 - libarchive 2.8.4
# tested in Bash shell on Mac OS X

# only list .htaccess files from archive
bsdtar -T <(echo '*/.htaccess') -tvzf archive.tar.gz
bsdtar --include='*/.htaccess' -tvzf archive.tar.gz
gnutar --wildcards '*/.htaccess' -tvzf archive.tar.gz

# only extract .htaccess files from archive
bsdtar -T <(echo '*/.htaccess') -xvzf archive.tar.gz
bsdtar --include='*/.htaccess' -xvzf archive.tar.gz
gnutar --wildcards '*/.htaccess' -xvzf archive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [pax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_%28Unix%29), the POSIX standard archive [utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html):

```
pax -r -s ':/\.htaccess:/.htaccess:' -s ':^\.htaccess:.htaccess:' -s ':.::'
```

(i.e. extract non-root `.htaccess` files and root `.htaccess` files as is; suppress all other files)